# How do I make a two way bind between a textbox and a listbox/bindinglistbox?

Tags: c#, data-binding, textbox, listbox

Is there a way to bind a textbox and a listbox/bindinglistbox to each other so that **when someone clicks an item in the listbox it goes into the textbox.**

I've managed to get the textbox -> listbox connection working by binding the listbox to a bindinglist and having the textbox populate that list, so I can type in the textbox and have it populate the listbox. But now I need the connection from the listbox -> textbox to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using data binding -

Add a property to your model and implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
public class TextHistory : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _selectedValue;
    public string SelectedValue 
    { 
        get {return _selectedValue;}
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedValue)
            {
                _selectedValue= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
            }
        }
 }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
                PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Assign the listbox databinding to be the model and property above, specifying the update mode to be `OnPropertyChanged` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode?view=netframework-4.8

```
//this is the binding model you use on your forms on the elements that require it
TextHistory binding = new TextHistory();

listbox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", binding, "SelectedValue", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Now if you update `TextHistory.SelectedValue` the value will be propagated to any object that has it assigned as a binding.

You can read more about databindings here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding

Using SelectedIndexChanged -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8

Assign a function to that event so that when you select something in the box, you can update the textbox.

Psuedo example -

```
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   string itemSelected = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

   textBox.Text = itemSelected;
}
```

Comment: The controls are on separate forms, the controls don't have access to each other so your example wouldn't work. (I think data binding is needed, or failing that events).

Comment: Do they share a model between them?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question (I'm new to this).

Comment: When you enter something into the textbox or listbox, where does that info get stored to? Do you have a class that you use?

Comment: Yes I do, it's called TextHistory, it contains a bindinglist<string> called HistoryList. This list is what the textbox populates and it's what is set as the listbox's datasource.

Comment: So you could bind the listbox selected value to a property on the TextHistory class. Then you can bind that property to the textbox text class so whenever the property in TextHistory is updated, your textbox will be too. I can update my answer with a pseudo one for you

Comment: Yes please show me an example, it sounds like you might have solved my issue!

Comment: Updated! It's not a copy and paste example so it might need some tweaks to fit what you currently have :)